# Como ordeno por año en Python, pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

en zonas tengo un campo fecha_fin y es un campo de fechas. lo que quiero es agruparlos por años,
tengo 2017 y 2016 y solo quiero mostrar a 2017

tengo esto:

```
file = pd.read_csv("zonas.csv",encoding='utf-8')
print('El promedio de costo de Tarifa por Base firme: ', file['capacidad_base_firme'].describe()['mean'])


print('La varianza del costo de Tarifa por Base firme: ', file['capacidad_base_firme'].describe()['std'])

file.groupby(file.fecha_inicio.dt.year)
```

Comment: Lo que has escrito con `groupby()` ya te agrupa por años (o debería hacerlo si el campo `fecha_inicio` es de tipo `datetime`). ¿Qué quieres hacer después con el grupo?

Comment: filtrar los datos por año y despues calcular el promedio de ciertas columnas que solo estan en ese año, no se si me explico

Comment: `file.groupby(file.fecha_inicio.dt.year).mean()` quizás?

Comment: lo probare, gracias

Comment: lo que paso, es que no habia formateado mi columna a tipo datetime

Answer (score 1):

Lo que hice fue revisar el tipo de datos de mis columnas:

```
file.dtypes
```

y converti mis columnas a tipo datetime

```
file["fecha_fin"]= pd.to_datetime(file["fecha_fin"])
file["fecha_inicio"]= pd.to_datetime(file["fecha_inicio"])
```

y al final agrupe,

```
file.groupby(file.fecha_inicio.dt.year).mean()
```